# Retrofit call does not show data

Tags: java, retrofit2

I make an API call using `Retrofit`, but instead of the data, I am getting what looks like the body.

My data is:

```
[{"rawMaterialName":"Bails"},{"rawMaterialName":"Tins"}]
```

The response I am getting is;

```
[com.example.retrofit_intro.model.RawMaterialModel@cb8f45d, com.example.retrofit_intro.model.RawMaterialModel@22291d2]
```

**Model:**

```
public class RawMaterialModel {
    @SerializedName("rawMaterialName")
    private final String rawMaterialName;

   
 public RawMaterialModel( String name)
    {

        
this.rawMaterialName = name;

    }
    


public String getRawMaterials() {
        return rawMaterialName;
    }
}
```

**MainActivity:**

```
interface getRawMaterials{
        @GET("/api/RawMaterial")
        Call<List<RawMaterialModel>> getrawMaterials();
    }

   
 Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("BASE_URL")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
                .build();



    
getRawMaterials requestRawMaterials = retrofit.create(getRawMaterials.class);         
        
requestRawMaterials.getrawMaterials().enqueue(new Callback<List<RawMaterialModel>>() {
            @Override
           
 public void onResponse(Call<List<RawMaterialModel>> call,    Response<List<RawMaterialModel>> response) {
                if(response.isSuccessful())
                {
                    if(response!=null)
                    {
                        List<RawMaterialModel> rawMaterialModelList = response.body();

                        Log.w("RAWLIST",rawMaterialModelList.toString());
                        ArrayAdapter<RawMaterialModel> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>  (MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, rawMaterialModelList);
                               

adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
                    }

                }

            }
```

I am populating a spinner and need `Bails and Tins`, but getting the weird `body` data instead.